# The Keras MultiHeadAttention() class does not return expected values

Tags: keras, tf.keras

I would like to match the results of the `self_attention()` function on page 339 of the Chollet's book, *Deep learning with Python*, second edition, with those of the `MultiHeadAttention()` example just below on the same page.

I wrote an example with the same input and I have different results. Can somebody explain why? I inserted the `self_attention()` function for clarity.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import softmax
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MultiHeadAttention


def self_attention(input_sequence):
    output = np.zeros(shape=input_sequence.shape)
    # The output will consist of contextual embeddinsgs of the same shape
    for i, pivot_vector in enumerate(input_sequence):
        scores = np.zeros(shape=(len(input_sequence),))
        for j, vector in enumerate(input_sequence):
            scores[j] = np.dot(pivot_vector, vector.T)  # Q K^T
        scores /= np.sqrt(input_sequence.shape[1])  # sqrt(d_k)
        scores = softmax(scores)  # softmax(Q K^T / sqrt(d_k))
        print(i, scores)
        new_pivot_representation = np.zeros(shape=pivot_vector.shape)
        for j, vector in enumerate(input_sequence):
            new_pivot_representation += vector * scores[j]
        output[i] = new_pivot_representation
    return output


test_input_sequence = np.array([[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                                 [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                                 [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]])

test_input_sequence.shape
# (1, 3, 4)

self_attention(test_input_sequence[0])
"""
returns
[[0.50648039 0.49351961 0.30719589 0.81367628]
 [0.23269654 0.76730346 0.38365173 0.61634827]
 [0.21194156 0.78805844 0.57611688 0.78805844]]

the attention scores being:
[0.50648039 0.18632372 0.30719589]
[0.23269654 0.38365173 0.38365173]
[0.21194156 0.21194156 0.57611688]
"""
att_layer = MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=1,
                               key_dim=4,
                               use_bias=False,
                               attention_axes=(1,))

att_layer(test_input_sequence,
          test_input_sequence,
          test_input_sequence,
          return_attention_scores=True)

"""
returns
array([[[-0.46123487,  0.36683324, -0.47130704, -0.00722525],
        [-0.49571565,  0.37488416, -0.52883905, -0.02713571],
        [-0.4566634 ,  0.38055322, -0.45884743, -0.00156384]]],
      dtype=float32)

and the attention scores
array([[[[0.31446996, 0.36904442, 0.3164856 ],
         [0.34567958, 0.2852166 , 0.36910382],
         [0.2934979 , 0.3996053 , 0.30689687]]]], dtype=float32)>)
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. This is due to the three dense layers before query, key, and value, and the one after the attention module  (this last dense layer is missing from Fig. 11.8 in the book).
To reproduce the results of `self_attention()`, we just need to have pass-through dense layers:

```
i_4 = np.identity(4)
w_pt_4 = [i_4.reshape(4, 1, 4) for _ in range(3)] + [i_4.reshape(1, 4, 4)]
att_layer.set_weights(w_pt_4)
```